# How to make flexbox children fill width of parent from parent class

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a div with 5 child divs. There is no content, it's just there to visually display a percentage. I have set a width and height on the parent and I want to find the easiest way to make the children equally fill that width. I can do this by adding `flex-grow` to each child but ideally I'd love to be able to control that from the parent.

**NB:** Code is using tailwindcss

```
<div class="flex w-64 h-2">
    <div class="flex-grow mr-1 rounded-l-lg bg-blue-dark"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow mr-1 bg-blue-dark"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow mr-1 bg-blue-dark"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow mr-1 bg-blue-dark"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow rounded-r-lg bg-gray-lighter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If all you're trying to do is show a percentage, then I'd suggest using a CSS gradient along with CSS custom properties, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hopqsLdu/

Answer (score 2):

You have "flexbox" in title but you did not mentioned in question that you actually you are forced to use flexboxes, just need to achieve equal divs.
So the best approach will be using [grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-flow) instead of flex, because it is just designed for that.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid grid-flow-col w-64 h-2">
    <div class="bg-blue-500"></div>
    <div class="bg-red-500"></div>
    <div class="bg-green-500"></div>
    <div class="bg-orange-500"></div>
    <div class="bg-gray-500"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good option but I'm specifically trying to see if that is possible with Flexbox.

Comment: Not without custom CSS